# SemEval-2013 Task 2 download error- urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Authorization Required

Tags: python, tweets

I tried to download SemEval-2013 Task 2 data. However, there's an error occured which is shown below. I mean I completely copy the API code so that this situation shouldn't happen.
[image]

Comment: Please paste your code and the output as text, don't use screenshots.